# Using "is" with TO BE verb, also have "how many + (plural noun) in the sentence?

Tags: passive-voice, plural-forms

Is it wrong to use **is** with *to be a verb* when it starts with **have how many days** (*plural noun*)? also is it correct to use the *passive form* verb; "**quarantined**" in the way?

> ***How many days is quarantined?***

Comment: You should note that ***to quarantine*** only really exists as a ***transitive*** verb. The full OED has intransitive definitions #2: *To institute quarantine regulations against a place, an infection, etc. **Obsolete***, and #3: *To go into quarantine. **rare***, but they're not really relevant. And the "object" of the transitive verb form can be people or places, but not ***days***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a short incorrect sentence, it's not obvious what the the speaker meant, and one can't point to just a single error in its construction.
As noted in the comment, "quarantine" is a transitive verb, so it can be passivized. It is also a noun. Here are two examples of correct use of the word that *may* be what the speaker intended:

1 **How many days is he quarantined for?**
This uses the verb "quarantine" in passive form, meaning "He is quarantined. I want to know how long the quarantine must last."

2 **How many days is the quarantine?**
This uses "quarantine" as a noun, and asks how long it must last.

Per comment by the OP, it seems this is what the sentence meant:

3 **"How many days is 'quarantined'"?**

that is, having heard the word "quarantined", someone jokingly wanted to know how many days that implied. Note that for that use, he should have used quotation marks around the word "quarantined".

Comment: Thanks, @Jack. I think the speaker meant is similar to your #2 example as a joke to his followers in his Instagram account with serious meaning to say he's tired of quarantine days he's spending indoor and don't know how many days passed (as a joke because he belives many days spent and it was a long time. But as you see in his sentence, he didn't use any "subjective pronouns" like "he" for himself or others for someone else like "she", "it", "we", "they",...

Comment: Okay, I understand better. He heard or read the word "quarantined" and wanted to know how many days that would be. I edited my answer to include that possibility.